# How can I get a WPF desktop application to catch a Elgato Streamdeck command with text characters?

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-core-3.1, streamdeck

I have a WPF desktop application written with NET Core 3.1 and it catches keystrokes with KeyDown command. All characters are caught with the keyboard. When I use a Streamdeck and its System Text feature, which sends keys like a keyboard my WPF app doesn't catch it.

Tested on Notepad and the text sent from the Streamdeck works as it should, e.g. X 1 Enter.

When I debug the only thing that gets sent is Enter key.

```cs
private void MyApp_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.X)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Everything works fine with a normal keyboard. Barcode Scanner works too. It's the Streamdeck that won't catch the text it sends.

Is there anything I need to set in my project to catch it?

[StreamDeck Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvdcO.png)

Comment: I am not a owner of SteamDeck but are you sure that it sends a series of key strokes? That function sounds like just pasting a predefined text. If it is the case, you cannot capture it as key strokes.

Comment: @emoacht how can I test if it is a predefined text? Why does it work in Notepad?

Comment: Have you tried TextBox control in WPF application? Can StreamDeck send text to the TextBox? If so, Key events are fired?

Comment: @emoacht when I send to the Textbox it is the same as Key Press....the only key that is sent is the Enter Key, all characters are ignored.

Comment: Digging into window message, I figured out how to capture it. I am writing the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself am interested in Elgato Stream Deck a little and so tried Stream Deck Mobile app. I found when the app sends a text, a pair of `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` windows messages with `VK_PACKET` [virtual-key code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) are sent for each letter. It suggests the app utilizes SendInput function to "send Unicode characters as if they were keystrokes".

Then, luckily I found `UIElement.PreviewTextInput` event can capture each letter. So, assuming the text ends with Enter key, we can retrieve the text sent by the app by aggregating the letters.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private readonly StringBuilder _buffer = new();

    protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Text is ("\r\n" or "\r" or "\n")) // Key.Return produces a line break.
        {
            if (_buffer.Length > 0)
            {
                OnTextRecieved(_buffer.ToString());
                _buffer.Clear();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _buffer.Append(e.Text);
        }
        base.OnPreviewTextInput(e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnTextRecieved(string text)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"TextRecieved {text}");
    }
}
```

Comment: will try this...thank you so much....does this replace the keydown event if I need to be able to capture the key entry from whatever device the user decides to use? e.g. keyboard, barcode scanner

Comment: Probably no. It depends but you need to prepare for each input device or input method if you wish to capture all of them.